# What is the basis of the use of Hermitian matrices as quantum gates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-computer, unitarity

Because all quantum gates must be unitary matrices, it is possible to prove the no cloning theorem by showing that no quantum gate can output two identical copies of an arbitrary inputted qubit.

This lead me to the question of why are quantum gates modeled using unitary matrices in the first place? Why does every action in a quantum system have to be reversible? Why does not being able to clone a qubit mean we can't clone a qutrit or any other quantum particle/configuration/system?

Assuming these things is very useful in quantum computing, but I want to know what is the quantum mechanical basis of representing these things as solely unitary matrices and nothing else.

EDIT: Clarified question.

Comment: "why are qubits modeled using Hermitian matrices"?  This is not clear. qubits are simply a quantum superposition of two possible values. But you can operate a qubit on a nonhermition matrix (it just causes loss in coherence), which is something that's done at the end of a quantum computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't true:

> all quantum gates must be Hermitian.

Instead, quantum gates must be (i) **unitary** and, as a pre-requisite, (ii) **linear**. The no-cloning theorem rests exclusively on the latter, via mechanisms that are explained in depth e.g. in [the Minute Physics explainer on the No-Cloning Theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owPC60Ue0BE).

The linearity of quantum gates itself is a core postulate of quantum mechanics, and we know of no deeper principle from which you can explain it. In fact, the principle that quantum gates must be linear is the correct understanding of the principle that matter has a wave nature. We can't really say *why* that's the case; we just know that it happens.

Comment: Ahh my bad, also why do quantum gates have to be unitary?

Comment: To preserve probability.

Comment: @OzanerHansha Comments are not for extended discussion. If you have additional query, take your time to compose them up into a self-contained new question. But yes, that is (roughly) correct.

Answer (score 0):

If a gate is represented by a Unitary and Hermitian matrix, the reversibility happens with a application of the same gate twice (H^2=I,  X^2=I), but if the matrix is only Unitary, there is another gate that reverse that gate .